# How to set different data on ajax call for different function - Jest Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```js
const req = useAxios(getData1).onData((data) => {});
....
....
const req = useAxios(getData2).onData((data) => {});

it('container should be render with component', () => {
    const setAxios = (index) => {
      let data = {};
      if (index === 1) {
        dat1 = { 'test' : '123' };
      }
      if(index === 2) {
        data = { 'test' : '345' };
      }
      useAxios.mockReturnValue(mockUseAxios(withData(data)))
    }
    getdata1.mockReturnValue(setAxios(1));
    getdata2.mockReturnValue(setAxios(2));
    const {container} = render(<Component />);
    expect(container.firstChild).toHaveClass('overview');
});
```

The mock is always set to index `2`. How do I return 2 different data based on given methods? The mock sets the most recent value and it is not changing.

Comment: could you share details about useAxios, and getData functions? Your code looks a little tangled, it's not clear how it works

Answer (score 0):

`useAxios.mockReturnValue()` mocks only a single return value. If you call it again, it will overwrite the first value (returning 2 instead of 1).

If you know the order it will be called, you can use `mockReturnValueOnce()` ([Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvalueoncevalue)):

```
useAxios.mockReturnValueOnce(mockUseAxios(withData(data)))
```

If the order can change or you don't want to rely on the order, you can use `mockImplementation()` ([Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn)). You'll only want to do this once or it will overwrite, so you shouldn't put this in your `setAxios` function:

```
useAxios.mockImplementation(param => {
    // return based off param
    return param === 'hello' ? { 'test': 123 } : { 'test': 456 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am unable to follow. Can you please update my code and suggest.

Comment: Replace `mockReturnValue` with `mockReturnValueOnce` and your code should work.

Comment: I did tried and it is not working as expected. Can you please rewrite my code and suggest what it has to be.

Comment: "Not working as expected" is really unclear. What specifically is going wrong? Also I should point out that since `setAxios` returns undefined, both `getdata` functions return undefined.